# Matplotlib: blank plot and window won't close

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a curve using the data from a csv file using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from csv import reader

with open('transmission_curve_HST_ACS_HRC.F606W.csv', 'rw') as f:
         data = list(reader(f))
         wavelength_list = [i[0] for i in data[1::]]
         percentage = [i[1] for i in data[1::]]

plt.plot(wavelength_list, percentage)
plt.show()
```

But all it make is opening a completely blank window and I can't close it unless I close the terminal.

The csv file looks like this:

```
4565,"0,00003434405472044760"
4566,"0,00004045191689260860"
4567,"0,00004656394357747830"
4568,"0,00005267963655205460"
4569,"0,00005879949856084820"
```

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Could you please add few example lines of your `csv` file?

Comment: Yes, my csv file contains 2 columns, like this:

4.564000000000000000e+03 2.824029270045730361e-05

Comment: I have tried changing the cells format to non scientific format for the data just in case but it doesn't change anything

Comment: How long is your file? I would try numpy: `import numpy as np; x,y = np.loadtxt("filename.csv", skiprows=1, unpack=True); plt.plot(x,y)`

Comment: My file has 2745 lines. When using numpy I have the error message `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 4565,"0,00003434405472044760"`

Comment: This is a different format than you report in the second comment here. Mind that decimal seperator should not be a comma, and you would need to remove the `""`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify three things in your code:

1. Change `'rw'` to `'r'` when you read from the file
2. Correct the way you iterate over data
3. Convert the numbers from the second column to `float`

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from csv import reader

with open('transmission_curve_HST_ACS_HRC.F606W.csv', 'r') as f:
         data = list(reader(f))
         wavelength_list = [i[0] for i in data]
         percentage = [float(str(i[1]).replace(',','.')) for i in data]

plt.plot(wavelength_list, percentage)
plt.show()
```

Content of the `csv` file:

```
4564,"0,00002824029270045730"
4565,"0,00003434405472044760"
4566,"0,00004045191689260860"
4567,"0,00004656394357747830"
4568,"0,00005267963655205460"
4569,"0,00005879949856084820"
```

[image]

Comment: I used 'rw' because it was part of a bigger script but yes indeed in this case 'r' is enough. I tried with your way but i get the error `IndexError: list index out of range` for percentage

Comment: Probably in the actual csv file you have a different delimiter than ‘space’ and you overlooked it (e.g ‘tab’ instead of ‘space’). Just exactly the same delimiter as in the actual file and it will work

Comment: Yes it makes sens, but how do I know wich delimiter it is ?

Comment: In general - open the file using editor which shows what type of whitespace character is used (e.g. Notepad++ or Sublime Text). In your case, if you don't see anything in between the elements (like coma or semicolon), you already tried with 'space' and didn't work -  try `delimiter='\t'`. It's not like you have a lot of possibilities there ;)

Comment: When using Sublime Text, i get this for example: `4564,"0,00002824029270045730"` so i guess ',' is the delimiter, but when using this i still get the same error message

Comment: Can you edit your question and copy paste a small piece (preferably more than one line) of the actual csv file you're trying to process over there, not in the comments? This snippet looks completely different then the one you added in the first place and it becomes a long discussion over a rather simple issue.

Comment: Check it now. Since `,` is the delimiter, you don't need to specify it. It's a default one.

Comment: Well I do not have the error for the range anymore, but still the window that is opening is blanck :/

Comment: The graph in the answer is a result of executing the snippet above and certainly it isn't blank. Maybe you're trying to execute slightly different/modified piece of code and the problem is in a different place?

Comment: Well I am executing exactly the piece of code you advised, the only different is that I use all of the csv file rather that the only two data you used as an example :/

Comment: I just run this code with a file of ~3k lines and it does work. Matplotlib sweats a bit more while plotting but except that nothing changes. If your machine cannot handle this amount of data then try to reduce the amount of points before plotting it.

Comment: Well it seems you were right, it just took a bit of time to my machine to process it ! Thank you for your help, it works just fine now :)